# This one came to me while I was watching Power Rangers

Tags: riddle, visual

Can you guess the word from the following images?

[image: Actor]

[image: Dessert]

[image: Galaxy]

[image: Land]

[image: Reaper]

[image: Tree]

Comment: Don't want to be the boring guy at a party here, but the Topic is very bad chosen for Stack... - standards

Comment: @OleAlbers That's how this particular stack works, actually, assuming by "topic", you mean the title of the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Clearly:

> Angel

Charley Chaplin

> Charley's Angels (annoyed I didn't get that straight away)

A Cake

> Angel Cake (some kind of fairy cake simile?)

Guardians of the galaxy

> Guardian Angels

An island

> Angel Island (had to google it like...)

The Reaper / Death

> An Angel of Death

A weeping willow tree

> Weeping Angels (A Dr Who villain - I don't usually watch it but I did like that Sally Sparrow episode!)

Title

> In the original series of power rangers, the main cast lived in 'Angel Grove'

Comment: Correct! Good Work!

Comment: The Cake is an Angel Food Cake https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_food_cake